# How can I modify the Document Library Upload Form?

Tags: document-library, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

I'll be as specific as possible for this issue as I haven't found anyone of my normal resources that can help me out with this one.

I have a Document library that we would like to have a field that pulls a string of data into a dropdown list from the User Profile.  I can do this in any form that I can edit with InfoPath 2010, but the upload form for a Document Library cannot be edited in SharePoint.  (The data is a string of Office Numbers separated by a ";". ie. 0001; 0002; 0003...)

I thought creating another form with the data that I'd like to pass through to the form for the Document Library would work.  There isn't a connection option for the Document Library Form webpart when choosing Edit Webpart.

So, I'm thinking that my only option now is to find some way of using JQuery or other code to pass the data from an InfoPath 2010 form to the Document Library form.  I am not all that code savy, so I'm hoping one of the many guru's out here can lend me a helping hand...

Challenge...   Extended...

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution would be to [create an EventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407965.aspx) for the ItemAdded event of the list that would then lookup and populate the Office Numbers field of the item after the document was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit of challenge to understand your terminology and the question

> I have a Document library that we would like to have a field that
>   pulls a string of data into a dropdown list from the User Profile. I
>   can do this in any form that I can edit with InfoPath 2010, but the
>   upload form for a Document Library cannot be edited in SharePoint

IMO, the fields are in a (Infopath) **form template** and the different form templates are in a **Form Library** not in **Document Library** which is for forms with data and/or documents (based on form or **document template**s). Otherwise it will be a inextricable never-ending mess.

> I thought creating another form with the data that I'd like to pass
>   through to the form for the Document Library would work. There isn't a
>   connection option for the Document Library Form webpart when choosing
>   Edit Webpart.

Probably you mean a **"form template:** under "form".
In order to have connections (or any exposure at all) you should have promoted fields while publishing a form template

[image]

and/or have inserted into created web part page (ASPX) an Infopath Form Web Part for already created in Infopath Designer 2010 Infopath form.
To the best of knowledge, I doubt that there is any coding or non-coding development platform except MS Office Infopth Designer that can create an Infopath form.

First, this can and should be done codelessly (without code).

Second, if you cannot manage to do it codelessly, the coding platforms will not help.  The Infopath development is based on **add-on principles**, one adds code, if it is possible at all depending on many factors (custom coding is not available for Infopath forms on many circumstances), to already existing codeless solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I am pretty sure what he asking for is to customize the document library properties form using InfoPath...

If this is true you are actually wanting to modify the content type Document Information Panel. Please use the link below to do this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms563688(v=office.14).aspx

Hope this helps.
SG.