# Customize the upload form of a document library

Tags: document-library, infopath, custom

how can I customize the upload form of a document library using Infopath. Is there any possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any possibility?**

**As a short answer:** there is **no** any type of possibility to customize the `upload.aspx` using **InfoPath**.

---

[Update]

**Any other way than InfoPath?**

**Depends on** your type of customization, check these threads

- [How can I modify the Document Library Upload Form?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38864/how-can-i-modify-the-document-library-upload-form)
- [Modification of '_layouts/upload.aspx'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx)
- [Modification of '_layouts/upload.aspx'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx)
- [Custom upload page in Layouts for document library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/syedi/2008/07/18/custom-upload-page-in-layouts-for-document-library-and-its-navigation-from-upload-menu-in-the-toolbar-bend-it-custom-upload-menu-for-the-document-library/)
- Or google it at [custom upload form for document library in sharepoint 2013](https://www.google.com.sa/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEU_enSA821SA821&ei=7YMDXJmWO7iO1fAPi-yEWA&q=custom%20upload%20form%20for%20document%20library%20in%20sharepoint%202013&oq=Customize%20the%20upload%20form%20of%20a%20document%20library%20&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i30l3.7037914.7037914..7040731...0.0..0.407.407.4-1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.nGaZrb7nm5Q)

Comment: any other way than InfoPath ? @Mohamed El-Qassas

Comment: What's the SharePoint version?

Comment: 2013 @Mohamed El-Qassas

Comment: I have a question. Can I customize the upload form of a doc lib using nintex @Mohamed El-Qassas

Comment: You can build your own forms in a document library using Nintix, please check this https://community.nintex.com/blogs/NintexProductBlog/2017/11/20/fresh-off-the-press-forms-file-upload-control-in-nintex-workflow-cloud also it's recommended to ask about Nintix in their forum because it's not allowed in the Stack Exchange   https://community.nintex.com/community/build-your-own Also, please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you, Thanks!